# rails migration one by one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Is there a possibility to run migrations one at a time?

I've got a bunch of migration files and the whole migration runs without problem on my local machine (which use PostgreSQL).

When I deploy (the server uses MySQL), the whole migration does not succeed.

Therefore, I'd like to reset the database and run migrations one by one to see where the inconsistency arises.

P.S. The problem seems to be with pluralization: script can not drop column **order_id** from table NNN, which in fact contain **orders_id** column.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails 3.0 introduced `rake db:forward` which accepts a `STEP` parameter:

```
rake db:forward STEP=1
```

Comment: This kind of command is exactly what I need, but when I type it (with different values of STEP paramater), I've got no output and no table is created. I use Rails 3.2.13, and one of the first migrations are

20130304080313_create_items.rb

20130304080838_create_orders.rb

The first of them, contains for example

class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    create_table :items do |t|

      t.string :name

      t.text :description

      t.string :status

      t.timestamps

    end

  end

end

Comment: This indicates that there are no outstanding migrations, i.e. your database is up to date. You can check the status with `rake db:migrate:status`

Answer (score 0):

Running migrations one by one is possible by passing a `STEP=number` parameter.

```
rake db:forward STEP=1 # edited as per Stefan's suggestion
rake db:rollback STEP=1
```

Comment: `rake db:migrate` seems to ignore the `STEP` argument.

Comment: You're right, `rake db:migrate` only takes a `VERSION=2013.....` argument. `rake db:forward` would be more convenient in this case. Thanks a lot!